# Using custom attributes in DOM elements, with boolean value

Tags: html, custom-attributes

Is there a way to add attributes to a DOM element with boolean value like this:

```
<body test='false'></body>
```

I need to set this without using javascript.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? It is a boolean value. Do you mean 1 or 0? Then, you'll need to change how you write it. How do you write it?

Comment: No there isn't. Attributes are always strings in HTML. Depending on what you are going to do with this attribute you might need to parse it. Also notice that according to the w3c spec there's no `test` attribute defined on the `body` tag meaning that your HTML is not valid.

Comment: The fact that something is a valid boolean is only relevant in the context of a programming language. If you are not using javascript... where do you need to retrieve the value as a boolean? (and why did you tag this question with `javascript` in the first place)

Comment: @Darin: What you should say is that his HTML won't *validate* under a given schema. It's *valid* HTML, and indeed the approach of custom attributes is widely used.

Comment: @silky: No, it’s not valid HTML. It is valid SGML but it’s not valid HTML.

Comment: @Gumbo: Okay, I accept the point, but my underlying comment stands. (I can't edit it to correct it.)

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, Thanks. This may be for another question, but aside for not being officially defined, what would be the problem with using it? Isn't it the same if javascript'd: window.document.body.test = "false";? I mean what engine doesn't load that HTML?

Comment: @Pablo Fernandez, it's for VBScript, it loads a ActiveX browser. I'll access the attribute from there.

Comment: So you want to add the `test` field to the `<body>` without using javascript, to later parse it in vbscript? is that right?

Comment: @Carlos Ok, allow me the freedom to edit your question and my answer. Let see how it goes.

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 has something called [data-attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) that might fit your needs. You could do something like this:

```
<body data-test="true"></body>
```

And then check the boolean value of the attribute like this (using jQuery):

```
!!$('body').attr('data-test')
```

**Explanation of the "double bang" operator:**

You can get the boolean value of **any** javascript object like this:

```
!!0 //false

!!1 //true

!!undefined //false

!!true //true
```

**Edit**

As noted by David, a non-empty string (like "false" for example) would yield true.

You've got 2 options here:

- dont set the attribute, which will be undefined and hence `false`
- compare to the string "true" instead of using the !! operator

Hope that helps!

Comment: … but the string `"false"` is `true`

Comment: That is quite a big edit … which doesn't address the problem `!!"false" // true`